# Prisma connect a new many-to-many journey to an existing user

Tags: node.js, prisma

I'm using Prisma and I have the following 3 tables (users, journeys and journeyUser)

```
model User {
  id        String        @id @unique @default(uuid())
  email     String
  firstname String
  lastname  String
  role      UserRole      @default(MEMBER)
  account   Account?      @relation(fields: [accountId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  accountId String
  journeys  JourneysOnUsers[]
}

model Journey {
  id        String        @id @unique @default(uuid())
  name      String        @unique
  account   Account?      @relation(fields: [accountId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  accountId String
  users     JourneysOnUsers[]
}

model JourneysOnUsers {
  journey   Journey     @relation(fields: [journeyId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  journeyId String
  user      User        @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  userId    String
  purpose   UserPurpose

  @@id([journeyId, userId])
}
```

**Now in my code I would like to attach/connect a certain number of Users to a Journey.**

### I've tried

#### 1. This gives me the following error

`TS2322: Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Enumerable<JourneysOnUsersWhereUniqueInput> | undefined'.`

```
await prisma.user.update({
            where: { id: user.id },
            data: {
                journeys: {
                    connect: { id: journeyId } // error here
                }
            }
        })
```

#### 2. the following code

but I get an error saying
`TS2322: Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Enumerable<JourneysOnUsersWhereUniqueInput> | undefined'.`

```
export const addUsersToJourney = async (journeyId: string, users: UserWithJourneys[]) => {
    for (const user of users) {
        await prisma.journey.update({
            where: {
                id: journeyId,
            },
            data: {
                users: {
                    create: { // I've also tried connect here
                        id: user.id,
                    },
                },
            },
            include: {
                users: true
            }
        })
    }
}
```